# How far apart can grounding rods be for a 200 amp panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding

I am having a 200 amp panel upgrade. The panel is on the back of the house. I spoke with the electrician, and he wants to use 2 grounding rods. One will go directly underneath the panel and he wants to put the other in the front of the house. Now, I know the 2 grounding rods have to be at a minimum 6 feet apart, but is there a maximum length the rods can be from one another? Thanks for any input.

Comment: Have you asked him why?

Comment: No, no limits except they need to be near the house. 6 feet is the cheap builder/slumlord bare minimum. As long as one is near the panel, farther apart is better because it will do a better job at the actual reason we use them (other than because code makes us).  Sounds like the guy likes doing pro work, I wouldn't discourage it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, sounds like an answer.

Comment: But you have to tie the two grounding rods together, right?  So that means running (and burying) #8 or #6 cable between the two rods, which increases the install and material cost?

Comment: Thanks Harper. Shevesh, this is what I was thinking, but as long as he is doing it for a legitimate reason and not just padding the bill.

Comment: If it is really from one side of the house to the other - as opposed to from, for example, the back but right next to a corner to the front but right next to the corner (two corners on the same side of the house) - then the easy/cheaper path would *not* be outside, requiring either conduit or burial, but through the inside of the house. Similar to running a ground wire to the water pipe entrance. If you have an unfinished basement (or drop ceiling or accessible crawlspace) then that will save a lot of time. **But does code allow that or does it have to be panel -> rod 1 -> rod 2 (i.e., all**

Comment: **outside once you get outside)?**

Comment: That's a very good question, manassehkatz. The electrician says he will be here when the inspection takes place, so I'm guessing he knows.

Answer (score 2):

NEC is not to be confused with *Magnolia Magazine*.  It's not a design guide for quality homes, nor is it even a "best practice".  NEC defines the *slumlord bare minimum, beneath which, a home is considered unsafe and unfit for human habitation and will not receive an occupancy permit*.

So 6 feet is the level at which an inspector cannot deny the slumlord the occupancy permit.  However, if you actually look at, you know, *the reason* a bunch of scientists and engineers thought that rule was needed... as long as one is quite near the panel, farther apart is better because it will do a better job of keeping the dirt around your house near the voltage of your system ground and neutral.

The UK has, um, *not that*... and they're having a heck of a time charging EVs safely. A simple failure in the utility wiring can result in a "hot skin" condition on the EV. It's even worse for boats and RVs.